# Proving the range of a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

**Prove** the range of the following two functions.
1)  f(x)=$(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2})$ for each x $ \in$ R.

2)  g(x)=$\sqrt\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ for each x $ \in$ (-1,1].

Since f(x) is not one to one f inverse can't be computed.In this sort of situations how can I **prove** what the range is ?

In g(x)  since this is one to one I computed the inverse which I get as g$^{-1}$(x)=$\pm$$\sqrt\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$. Here should I take the negative square root also or should it only be the positive one?

When I consider the domain of this inverse function since $\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$>=0. 
 I get 1>=x$^2$
.
Thus x $\in$ [-1,1]. Hence the rsnge of g is  **[-1,1]**

But I think this is wrong because in **g** , x $ \in$ (-1,1].When x=1 g(x)=0 and when x is close to -1, g(x) goes to infinity.Thus the range of g should be **[0, infinity).**

What have I done wrong here ? Please help to find the range of these two functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: for $\;a\in\Bbb R\;$

$$\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=a\iff(1+a)x^2=1-a\iff\ldots$$

Can you see what the condition(s) must be to solve the above for $\;x\;$ ?

Likewise with the other function:

$$\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}=a\iff 1-x=a^2+a^2x \iff (a^2+1)x=1-a^2\iff\ldots$$

But in this case you *also* must take into account that the function is defined only when

$$\frac{1-x}{1+x}>0\;,\;x\neq-1\iff \frac{x-1}{x+1}<0\;,\;x\neq -1\iff -1<x<1\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have some bound say $a>0$
$$\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\leq a \Rightarrow 1-x^2\leq a+ax^2 \Rightarrow (a+1)x^2 +(a-1) \geq 0$$
Do you think this holds true for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

For second question as you are guessing range includes $[0,\infty)$ what you could do is :

Take any $a >0$ then try finding some $x\in (-1,1]$ such that $\sqrt\frac{1-x}{1+x}>a$..

Can you do that?